# Fail to post to URL with "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path"

Tags: java, android, url

This is my url

```
String serverUrl = http://mob.krill.order-line.co.uk/MobileService.svc/UploadFile/721/Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png
```

here `Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png` is just name of file which is dynamically given to string.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
```

I get:

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 76: http://mob.krill.order-line.co.uk/MobileService.svc/UploadFile/721/Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png`

what are the remedies?

Comment: See: [Java URL encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding).

Comment: use escape sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per above suggestion my code worked with below solution

```
String fileName = f.getName();
            try {
                fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {             
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String serverUrl = http://mob.krill.order-line.co.uk/MobileService.svc/UploadFile/721/+fileName;
```

Answer (score 5):

You should URL encode the String.

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode (
    "http://mob.krill.order-line.co.uk/MobileService.svc/UploadFile/721/Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png",
    "UTF-8");
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(encoded);
```

EDIT, as was correctly commented by Duncan, if your URL contained a query String, which contains the characters `?` and `&`, you wouldn't want to URL-encode those. You would only encode the Strings containing problematic characters.

Comment: Most things [I've read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10786112/474189) suggest that the encoding should only be done on the "dodgy" parts of the URL. Your approach would work in this case, but wouldn't if query strings were used in due course. It would be better to split the URL to identify just the `Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png` part.

Comment: @Duncan: Thanks for your suggestions! solution found by your comment!